# Application of Santalo’s formula

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesics

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a compact smooth Riemannian manifold with a smooth boundary and suppose that $f$ is a smooth function on $M$ with the property that
$$ \int_I f(\gamma(t))\,dt=0,$$
for any inextendible unit speed geodesic $\gamma:I\to M$.

Does it follow that
$$ \int_M f\,dV_g=0?$$

Comment: are you assuming that the boundary of $M$ is convex? you also need to assume that $M$ is orientable to have an integral. under those assumptions this indeed immediately follows from Santalo's formula. You just have to lift $f$ in the obvious way to the unit normal bundle.

Comment: I was curious about the optimal assumptions. Orientability is assumed but I was not sure if nontrapping assumption and convexity of the boundary is required.

Comment: oh I see. I forgot about nontrapping, it is of course also necessary for the standard Sanatlo's formula.  I am not sure how necessary those conditions are. I think convexity of the boundry can be dropped. you can extend the manifold by a collar to get the boundary of the extended manifold to be convex and extend $f$ by 0.